# Multinominal vs Ordinal regression

Tags: spss

What is the difference between ordinal and nominal regression? If i want to run driver analysis after regression and have 3 variables, the DV is 5 point scale question with options "Very good, good, just right, bad, very bad" and 2 IVS with 7 point likert scale. What is the suggested regression for this type of scenario?

Comment: "just right" should be the middle of a scale that has "too much" and "not enough" on the sides. It isn't the middle for "very good" and "very bad"...

Answer (score 3):

Ordinal regression assumes that the categories of the DV are ordered. Multinomial assumes the categories are unordered. Consequently, if your DV's categories are ordered, the ordinal model is generally regarded as the appropriate one.

In a technical sense though, your categories are unordered. "Just right" seems to me to be superior to "Good". This would make the multinomial model more appropriate. But, a better model yet would allow for the possibility that people would have misread the question.

However:

- When people read survey questions, they often ignore poor wordings, and even though the categories are not ordered, may answer them as if they are actually ordered. This argues in favor of ordinal.
- Given that your goal with driver analysis is to have a single coefficient for each independent variable, this also argues in favor of ordinal, as multinomial will give you 4 parameters for each of the independent variable.

What I would also recommend is doing a sensitivity analysis, whereby you create the model using Ordinal, and then re-run it with the first three categories merged, and check that the conclusions are similar.

Comment: The fact that the dependent/left-hand-side/explained/y-varialbe is ordinal is a necessary but not a sufficient condition for using ordinal regression. Ordinal regression gains simplicity by making some strong assumptions, that only make sense when the y-variable is ordinal. In particular, the proportional odds/parallel lines assumption. However, strong assumptions can be wrong for your data even if the y-variable is ordinal. So that needs to be checked.